# Creating member function template specialization in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a class in which I want to create member function template specialization like this

```
namespace aha
{
class Foo
{
public:
    template < typename T >
    T To() const
    {
        // some code here
    }
};
template <>
bool Foo::To < bool > () const
{
    // some other code here
}
}
```

gcc is giving the error:

> Explicit instantiation of 'To < bool >' after instantiation

I would like to do it with template specialization of member functions only so that the users of my library would get the same function while converting `Foo` to different datatypes like

```
Foo obj;
bool b( obj.To < std::string > () );
int i( obj.To < int > () );
float f( obj.To < float > () );
```

and so on.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong in the code.

Comment: Your example compiles fine with g++ 4.6.3.

Comment: Do you mean "Explicit *specialization* of 'To<bool>' after instantiation"? Are you using `To<bool>` somewhere before you specialize it?

Comment: Compiles fine with gcc-4.7.2 and Comeau C++ Online. Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Explicit instantiation of 'To < bool >' after instantiation

The above says it all: it gets specialized after the generic version of it has already been used.

Function template specialization can be simulated with overloading, which is a more flexible mechanism (for example, there is no partial specialization for function templates, yet one can achieve the desired effect with overloading):

```
template<class T> struct Type {}; // similar to boost::type<>

class Foo
{
    template<class T>
    T doTo(Type<T>) const; // the generic version

    bool doTo(Type<bool>) const; // an overload for bool only
    // add more overloads as you please

public:
    template < typename T >
    T To() const {
        return this->doTo(Type<T>());
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you forget `const` on your `doTo` methods?

Comment: @Mark No, I did not forget const in my doTo methods.
Your technique solves my problem. However, I am not sure what is the need of 
    template<class T> struct Type {};
I made my doTo methods with simple non template types like this
    bool doTo( bool ) const;
and it works fine.

Comment: @SaurabhSinha `Type<T>` creates a distinct type for T, not convertible to any other `Type<U>`. It is useful primarily overload functions based on the exact type of the argument. Like in the code above.